# POST collection type data from silverlight to aspx page.

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a problem posting the data from silverlight to the aspx page which is in same domain.
I need to open aspx page in a new tab that needs data of type combination (id, amount) like 

3-XX-YY-ZZ, 12

4-XX-YY-ZZ, 20

5-XX-YY-ZZ, 15 

etc...[many]

 
and process it and display.

I tried to do it using querystrings and HtmlPage.PopupWindow(). It works but that would come with size limits.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can access javascript from silverlight application. And this problem was solved by using javascript function from silverlight to post the hidden field data to aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a HTTP post with WebClient api. This would help you to post data as a web page will do it.

Here is a link which I found this might be helpful to elaborate next steps...

http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/making-a-http-post-in-silverlight-a-k-a-thread-hopping/

HTH

Comment: Ok this helps in posting the data. But i also want to open the aspx page in the new window. How can I do that.

Comment: you can add the target attribute to your post and set it to _blank this should open a new window. But if you want to just link from a silverlight control you could also use a hyperlink control and set the uri to your targe with parameters. http://server.com?param=val1&param2=val2

Comment: Its late but I still have this problem. I get the response text. What should I do with it to open it in a new browser tab. Can you provide me some sample code for it.

Comment: Hi Prazana, any luck with opening in new window? I am facing the exact same issue